# How to reverse Newtonsoft JsonConvert PopulateObject

Tags: c#, json.net, event-sourcing

How can I diff 2 Json representations of 2 versions of an object, such that the output can be supplied to JsonConvert.PopulateObject(...) to convert the first version of the object to the second. For example:

```
public class Dog
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
}

var myDog = new Dog { Name = "Dio", Age = 1 };

var before = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDog); // { "Name": "Dio", "Age" : 1 }

myDog.Age++;

var after = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDog);   // { "Name": "Dio", "Age" : 2 }

// How do I generate this variable, so that I can use it with PopulateObject?
var ageIncrementJson = "{ \"Age\" : 2 }";

myDog = new Dog { Name = "Dio", Age = 1 };

JsonConvert.PopulateObject(ageIncrementJson, myDog);

// myDog should now have an age of 2
```

I've tried using JsonDiffPatch, but that produces a before-and-after document, which Newtonsoft doesn't accept (i.e. { "Age" : [ "1", "2" ] }

Comment: Well, after this line `JsonConvert.PopulateObject(ageIncrementJson, myDog);` the `Age` value of `myDog` is 2. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: So you want to generate `ageIncrementJson` when you only have the before and after `myDog` values?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, exactly.

Comment: @DavidG I *could* write something to tidy up the json string, removing the previous values, but that smells bad.

Comment: Is this the JsonDiffPatch you tried?  https://github.com/wbish/jsondiffpatch.net.

Comment: @dbc Yes, that's the one.